# How to pass "Content-Length" value in header using Curl Command

Tags: curl

How can I pass content-length eg. `--header Content-Length:1000` in curl command.
I used it like this in command but it did't work

```
curl -v -X POST -u "xxx@gmail.com:xxx123" \ 
     --header "Content-Length: 1000" \
     --header "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" \
     --header "X-REQUEST-ID:7fc7d038-4306-4fc5-89c3-7ac8a12a30d0" \
     -F "request={\"bumId\":\"d51f2978-5ce8-4c71-8503-b0ca438741dd\",\"fileType\":\"imageFile\"};type=application/json" \
     -F "file=@D:/file.pdf" \
     "http://localhost:9090/pro/v1/files"
```

This command posts file to a web services developed in Jersey Java

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `-d ""` causes CURL to send a `Content-Length: 0`,

see [Header 'Content-Length: 0' is missing when I do curl -X POST $URI](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/2183)

Comment: So whats the solution? remove the -d ?

Comment: @WenhanXiao the original example is missing the -d "" which causes curl to compute the content-length

Comment: see answer with -H for specific  header values.

Answer (score 13):

Adding a header like this should do the trick:

```
-H 'content-length: 1000'
```

Full example:

```
$ curl -v -XPOST -H 'content-length: 1000' https://example.com
# ... snip ...
> POST / HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Accept: */*
> content-length: 1000
>
# ... snip ...
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this: `curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/pro/v1/files -d "Content-Length: 0"`

`curl`'s `-d` flag allows you to add data to the body of the request. According to its docs:

> -d, --data 
>   (HTTP) Sends  the  specified data in a POST request to the HTTP
>   server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in
>   an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to
>   pass the data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would suggest adding an explanation to your answer so that people with a similar problem are better able to understand the solution. Perhaps explain what the `-d` flag is? Maybe add a snippet from the Curl manual?

Comment: are you sure this is correct? -d is to specify the data to be posted

Comment: Downvoted. `-d` is for request body. `-H` is for request header. By having `-d "Content-Length: 0"`, you are sending the text as the request body.