# Unable to retrieve access- and refresh-token

Tags: access-token, refresh-token, nest-api

Every time I try to retrieve the tokens via

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?
client_id=oauth2-client-id&
client_secret=oauth2-client-secret&
code=authorization-code&
grant_type=authorization_code&
redirect_uri=https://www.google.com'
```

(using my own client_id, secret and authorizationcode) I get an error instead of the two tokens. I restarted 5 or 6 times by deleting everything and create a new project but keep getting the same error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>411.</b> <ins>ThatΓÇÖs an error.</ins>
  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>ThatΓÇÖs all we know.</ins>
```

Who can help ? Thank you

Comment: Hi phil, have you tried adding a content-length-header? It is in the error message: "POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header" see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492178/how-to-pass-content-length-value-in-header-using-curl-command/45214187

Answer (score 0):

You will need to POST the parameters instead of sending them as query parameters, so use something like:

```
curl -L -d 'client_id=oauth2-client-id' -d 'client_secret=oauth2-client-secret' -d 'code=authorization-code' -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' -d 'redirect_uri=https://www.google.com' https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

in such a form cURL will also add the required `Content-Length` request header automatically.